# Extend a continuous function $f$ to be a function mapping into $\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Suppose we have a continuous function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is an unbounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For every sequence $\{x_n\} \subset U$ converging to the boundary $x \in \partial U$, we have $f(x_j) \to +\infty$. Note here I am not assuming the divergence to infinity to be uniform. Furthermore, if $\{x_j\} \subset U$ and $\|x_j\| \to \infty$, $f(x_j) \to +\infty$.

Now if we define $\hat{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$ by
\begin{align*}
  \hat{f} = \begin{cases}
     f(x), \qquad \text{ if } x \in U, \\
     +\infty, \qquad \text{ if } x \notin U.
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Is $\hat{f}$ continuous in the usual extended topology? I feel like the answer should be yes since sequentially $\hat{f}$ is continuous at every point. But since I am only assuming the divergence at the boundary to be sequential not uniform, I am not sure whether there are some subtleties I left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\hat{f}$ is continuous.  As you say, it is sequentially continuous, and that is all that is needed for continuity for a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or on any metric space).

It is not even necessary to stipulate that $f(x_j)\to+\infty$ when $\|x_j\|\to\infty$.  You only need $\hat{f}$ to respect sequences which actually converge in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: This should be a separate question. But the end goal of mine is to show the sublevel set $S_{\alpha} = \{x: f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is compact for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. It is apparently bounded by the assumption $f(x) \to \infty$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$. I was not sure whether it is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since continuity only tells us it is closed in the subspace $U$. But now if the extension is continuous, it should be closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since $S_{\alpha}$ is also equal to $ \{x : \hat{f}(x) \le \alpha\}$. Could you verify this argument? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You can also just prove it directly: if there is some sequence $(x_j)$ in $S_\alpha$ which converges to a point $x$ not in $S_\alpha$, then $x\not\in U$, since $S_\alpha$ is closed in $U$.  But then, by assumption, $f(x_j)$ goes to $+\infty$ and so the $x_j$ cannot all be in $S_\alpha$.